# regular expression to count number of dots for following format

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expressions. Can any one help me on how to count number of dots in 
below formate and limit to 4 dots using regular expression.
    a->test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1();

Comment: regex is not a tool for counting.

Comment: don't use regex. What language are you using? You could try looping through and counting if the `char == "."` or something like that. But regex is not the right choice here

Comment: What language? In Perl `my $count = () = $string =~ /\./g;`

Comment: regex-replace "[^.]" with "" and count length of resulting string?

Answer (score 1):

Counting dots in the string below using JavaScript

```
var s = 'a->test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1()';
console.log(s.match(/\./g).length);
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      import re
      x="a->test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1().test2().test1();"
      pattern=re.compile(r"\.")
      print len(pattern.findall(x))
```

This is in python.